# Yeoman - generator-angular error at init app deployment

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have installed npm, Yeoman and got everything working, the webapp generator works like a charm. I want to get into angular development and therefore tested the generator-angular.

I did everything as stated in the readme file

```
npm install -g generator-angular

yo angular [app-name]
```

then

```
grunt

grunt serve
```

at grunt i got this error:

WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/user/angular/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux)]: Connected on socket 3juFgfMcw5Pm88-cve27
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux) Controller: MainCtrl should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope FAILED
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

Answer (score 0):

The main error - is with **"unknown"** $routeProvider.
Check if ngRoute module has been loaded.
Also check that you propely injected it to your testApp module.
It would be great if you could provide your testApp code.

Also I guess that you have an error with regex (no escape symbol)

```
/home/user/angular/test/mock/**/*.js
```

Try this  "/home/user/angular/test/mock/*\.js"

```
/home/user/angular/test/mock/**/*\.js
```